# Spring Data error Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

My application throws the error while starting

Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: version of: org.mycompany.system.model.Code

My repository method

```
@Query("SELECT NEW org.mycompany.util.CodeVO(c.id,  c.description,c.version) FROM Code c where  c.groupName = :groupName")
    List<CodeVO> getByGroupName(@Param("groupName") String groupName);
```

Base class

```
public abstract class ModelObject<ID extends Serializable> implements Serializable {

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdTime = LocalDateTime.now();

    @Version
    private int version;

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }
    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

}
```

Sub class

```
 @Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "groupName", "description" }) })
public class Code extends ModelObject<Long> {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id; 

    @Column
    @NotBlank
    private String description;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

is it not possible to refer superclass properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ModelObject must be annotated with @MappedSuperclass there is no automatic inheritance in JPA

From the spec:

> 11.1.38 MappedSuperclass Annotation
>
> The MappedSuperclass annotation designates a class whose mapping information is applied to the entities that inherit from it. A mapped superclass has no separate table defined for it.