# Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: lastUpdateDate of: com.XXX.XXX.entity.Student

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, lombok

I already went through: [Spring Data error Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48081296/spring-data-error-caused-by-org-hibernate-queryexception-could-not-resolve-pro) and working on **Spring Data JPA PostGres lombok** example.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: An entity cannot be annotated with both @Entity and @MappedSuperclass: com.XXX.YYY.entity.Student
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.XXX.YYY.ProgramApplication.main(ProgramApplication.java:66) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: An entity cannot be annotated with both @Entity and @MappedSuperclass: com.XXX.YYY.entity.Student
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:532) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:250) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:274) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

**Student.java**

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table
public class Student extends AuditEnabledEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "studentId")
    private Long studentId;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

**StudentRepository.java**

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long>{
    @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
    @Query("UPDATE Student s SET s.firstName=:firstName, s.lastName=:lastName,"
            + "s.lastUpdateDate=NOW() WHERE s.studentId=:studentId")
    void updateDivision(@Param("firstName") String firstName,
                        @Param("lastName") String lastName,
                        @Param("studentId") Long studentId);
}
```

**AuditEnabledEntity.java**

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class AuditEnabledEntity {
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name="createDate", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Instant createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name="lastUpdateDate", nullable = false)
    private Instant lastModifiedDate;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

}
```

**Main.App**

```
private void saveStudent() {
        Student s = Student.builder().firstName("Joe").lastName("Kerr").build();
        studentRepository.save(s);

        studentRepository.updateDivision("Joe1", "Kerr1", 1L);
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a college project, We are not supposed to assist with them and it is for you to learn yourself: the error you need to pay attention to is clear and is this:  An entity cannot be annotated with both @ Entity and @ MappedSuperclass: com.XXX.YYY.entity.Student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear:

> An entity cannot be annotated with both @Entity and @MappedSuperclass:
>   com.XXX.YYY.entity.Student

Remove the annotation `MappedSuperclass` on the `Student` class.

You can also remove the `Table` annotation as long as the entity has the same name as the table.